# formatting django crispy form from model form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am using `django-crispy-forms` to generate a simple form which is shown in a jquery dialog box. My model is as follows:

```
class DummyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    time_points = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    more_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "dummy"
```

I use the `FormHelper` object in my `form` class to customize some lookout as shown in the crispy forms documentation as follows:

```
class DummyForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DummyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('name', css_class='input-xlarge'),
            Field('description', rows="3", css_class='input-xlarge'),
        )

    class Meta:
        model = DummyModel
        fields = ['name', 'description']
```

Now in my template, I do the following:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Dummy | Test {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div id="dialog" title="Edit" style="display: none;">
        <form method="post" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% crispy DummyForm %}

            <input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
        </form>
    </div>

    {% load static %}
    {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        function EditDialog() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
            return false;
        }
    </script>

     <div class="function-page">
         <div class="table-form">
                <div class="function-container">
                    {% render_table reviews %}
                </div>
         </div>
     </div>

{% endblock %}
```

The form is loaded when the `EditDialog()` javascript is called from a link and this creates a jquery dialog with the form in it.

However, my formatting does not seem to have any effect. For example, in the example gist here (https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms), the labels and components are laid out horizontally but they are laid out vertically for me. I also see a `*` next to the labels in the form, which is weird. The attached screenshot shows it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things left unexplained in that [gist](https://gist.github.com/maraujop/1838193) you referenced, along with a couple of ommissions. Additionally, you are trying to use [jQuery/jQuery UI for your dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/), and they are using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), without a dialog.

So let's address all of these things. First thing is the `DummyForm`. That gist does not include the necessary CSS classes (which come from Bootstrap) to provide the left/right layout. You need to add the `helper.label_class` and `helper.field_class` values. Also, there's a separate issue with your template that I'm addressing here: you shouldn't put the `<form>` tag in your template; crispy_forms will take care of that for you. This means you need to put your submit button into the form model's layout instructions, and *not* in your template.

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Field, ButtonHolder, Submit

class DummyForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DummyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        # NEW:
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-10'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('name', css_class='input-xlarge'),
            Field('description', rows="3", css_class='input-xlarge'),
            # NEW:
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn btn-primary')
            )
        )

    class Meta:
        model = DummyModel
        fields = ['name', 'description']
```

Next, we need to address your template. Here's an updated version that uses Bootstrap instead of jQuery UI. Note the use of `.modal()` instead of `.dialog()`, you can find more about the options [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). I've made some modest adjustments to make this a bit cleaner & to use the correct markup for the Bootstrap modal dialog, so let me know if any questions on the differences:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}Dummy | Test {% endblock %}</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js
"></script>

  <script>
    function EditDialog() {
      $("#dialog").modal();
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <button class="button" onclick="EditDialog()">CLICK TO SHOW DIALOG</button>

  <div id="dialog" class="modal" title="Edit" style="display:none">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          {% crispy DummyForm %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And that's the answer to how they got their gist to look the way they did: they're using Bootstrap, and they neglected to include a couple key lines of code in their example form class.

Comment: This is an awesome answer. i would upvote it a 100 times if I could! Thank you!